# Perl - Regex to find and replace ampersands that aren't part of a character entity

Tags: regex, perl, replace, find

So I am currently using the code:

```
$mystring =~ s/&/&#38;/g;
```

To find and replace all ampersands (`&`) in my string variable, and replace them with the XML entity reference for ampersands (`&#38;`). The problem is, I want to only replace ampersands that are NOT already part of an XML entity reference.

For example, say I did a find and replace before that to make all "`>`" to be "`&#62;`".

That has an ampersand, but I don't want the first bit of code to replace that, since it is followed by `#62;`.

It may not be enough to exclude "`&#`", as there is a slight chance that may be legitimately in the data. So can I in regex exclude where the ampersand is followed by "`#__;`"?

Alternatively, the specific three examples I want to exclude are "`&#44;`" (comma), "`&#62;`" (`>`), and "`&#60;`" (`<`). Those are the only other find and replaces I will be doing, so if there is a way to exclude those specifically, that would work too.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [`HTML::Entities`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities) to encode HTML entities in text. That way you don't have to come up with your own regex, realize you missed an entity, go back through with a second regex, and so on.

Comment: You didn't specify whether this was XML or HTML. I assumed XML, but the idea is similar for both. Fix as needed.

Comment: Mpost people use `&amp;` instead of `&#38;`. While perfectly valid, I've never even seen `&#38;`.

Comment: Once mixed, _real_ ampersand and _special_ ampersand are not actaully theoretically distinguishable. You should escape them earlier.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question.  You should do all your entity encoding in one pass.  A string should either be entity encoded or not.  Having a mixture is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
&(?!#\d+;)
```

This expression matches any ampersand character that is not followed by hash character with digits.

Here is [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eQ7uJ9/2) with more explanation.

Comment: If I wanted to modify that to include any ampersand not followed by #__;          where the __ are any number digit, how would I do that? Just as a precaution, in case there are any legitimate "&#" combinations in my data

Comment: $mystring =~ s/&(?!#\d{1,3};)/&#38;/g; would narrow the regexp a little bit further

Answer (score 4):

The syntax of XML character references is defined as

```
Reference     ::= EntityRef | CharRef
EntityRef     ::= '&' Name ';'
CharRef       ::= '&#' [0-9]+ ';'
                | '&#x' [0-9a-fA-F]+ ';'
Name          ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
```

So, the following will escape the `&` if it's not part of a valid reference.

```
my $name_start_char_class = ':A-Z_a-z\x{00C0}-\x{00D6}\x{00D8}-\x{00F6}\x{00F8}-\x{02FF}\x{0370}-\x{037D}\x{037F}-\x{1FFF}\x{200C}-\x{200D}\x{2070}-\x{218F}\x{2C00}-\x{2FEF}\x{3001}-\x{D7FF}\x{F900}-\x{FDCF}\x{FDF0}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{EFFFF}';
my $name_start_char       = qr/[$name_start_char_class]/;
my $name_char             = qr/[${name_start_char_class}\-.0-9\x{00B7}\x{0300}-\x{036F}\x{203F}-\x{2040}]/;
my $name                  = qr/$name_start_char$name_char*/;

s/&(?!(?:$name|#(?:[0-9]+|x[0-9a-fA-F]+));)/&#38;/g
```

Note that this assumes that your XML string contains no CDATA sections.

Comment: Nice review post. I wonder how  to match all tag names in your expression with elements in list  `quot, amp, lt, gt, nbsp, cent, pound, curren, euro` etc

Comment: @Max Zoom, In general, it's far better to separate checking if an identifier is known from the actual parsing. In this case, since we're trying to fix a bad document, it could help. For XML: `my  $name_pat = join '|', qw( amp lt gt quot apos ); my $name = qr/$pat/;`